# GWT 2.4 and XMPP integration with JBoss 7.1

Tags: xmpp, openfire, gwt2

I need integration between XMPP (Openfire server) and GWT(2.4).
I've already done it using plain JS.
My question is: what is the right way to connect to server from client.
I need basic functionality like chat. Only to send string messages to server and back.
I've seen **Strophe** (with a lot of native calls to JS) and **Emite** libraries but it seems that no one support them and they became old.
Can somebody paste code snippet for connection and exchanging messages? Thanks.

**edit:** I use JBoss 7.1.Final as a server

Comment: Basically i need pure java client code like Emite with "fresh" code inside so i think that i need to rewrite and throw away all garbage from emite :) and make it easy to use and modify. Any suggestions would help me!

Comment: did you resolve this yet? we are having the same problem atm

Comment: no i didn't. I've chosen basic html and js. If you have to use GWT then as a basic solution you can import strophe.js to main html page and then make native calls via java's *native* keyword or dynamically import using GWT's tools.

Comment: @DidarBurmaganov You can also connect to XMPP via Emite. I have been able to connect to Ejabberd XMPP server, following the example at https://github.com/EmiteGWT/emite/tree/0.7/examples. You need to use the proxy (check servlet mapping in web.xml)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for pure java client code, then you can used [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp), which is probably the most popular Java library for XMPP clients.

Comment: Thanks! This is what i needed because i use openfire so client also comes from jivesoftware :) But i can NOT use directly smack api in GWT. So to use it i downloaded smack's src, recompiled it to have .java & .class and added *.gwt.xml, place all in jar file and then in my application simply added <inherits 'path to smack module'>
or another workaround is just to place all src of smack directly to project structure (which looks a little insane :))

Comment: after some tries i failed :P to get it working because smack uses Socket and GWT compiler can not compile it. So Smack can not be used with GWT.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with GWT, but was addressing the fact that you said in your comment that you needed pure java client code.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking of something of this kind.
My application uses Google OAuth to login. Now, I want to implement chat in my application.
Whem I am logged into my application through, using this chat, I shall be able to chat with people on GTalk, gmail chat etc through the chat in my application.
That is I shall be able to chat with user in the application plus with users outside the application using group chat.

Any suggestions on "using what" can this be accomplished?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine supports XMPP (Google Talk :)). I think you could use it in GWT project. [GAE XMPP](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html)

Comment: Thanks for responce! I've already googled it but problem is that i do not use GAE. My stack is JBoss 7.1Final + openfire + GWT2.4 I can not switch to GAE. By the way is it possible to modify Google's XMPP Client sources to operate with my custom server? Would be nice

Comment: There are some libraries, but I didn't try them. It's up to you to choose :)
https://launchpad.net/gwt-strophe

Comment: Strophe have a lot of JSNI calls which i don't want to use because it becomes complicated with Java code mixed. Also when i tried it console during compilation printed such error:
[INFO] com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Failed to get JNode

Comment: Seems like there is no one can answer to your question man :D

Answer (score 0):

I personally used emite with hablar.  Whereas it may seem like a stale project now, it is open source and you can revive it. For example,  I have a pull request to both projects where I took the code that could only connect to a single xmpp server and modified it so that it can connect to multiple servers simultaneously.

Emite is a good start if you want just the communications stack and want to write something more custom for the ui than what hablar packages.

Hablar gives you a good base of what pieces you need for the ui.